# list the enum keys in CalendarApp.Color

Tags: javascript, enums, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Trying to get a list of the keys in the Google CalendarApp.Color enum in a Google Script with the following code:

```
var colors = CalendarApp.Color;
for (var x in colors) {
    Logger.log('Color Key: %s, Value: %s', x, colors[x]);
}
```

But it does not work, outputs:`[14-08-29 17:32:38:437 EDT] Color Key: toString, Value: function toString() {/*
*/}`

Is there something special about CalendarApp.Color?

EDIT:
Also tried;

```
var colors = CalendarApp.Color;
var cols;
for (var x in colors) {
    cols += colors[x];
}
Logger.log(cols);
```

That outputs: [14-08-29 10:04:43:582 EDT] undefinedfunction toString() {/*
*/}

Then Tried:

```
var colors = CalendarApp.Color
Logger.log("Color BLUE is: " + colors.BLUE);
var cols = Object.keys(CalendarApp);
Logger.log(cols);
```

Which Output:`[14-08-29 17:52:47:366 EDT] Color BLUE is: #2952A3
[14-08-29 17:52:47:367 EDT] [getTimeZone, createEventSeries, isMyPrimaryCalendar, createAllDayEvent, subscribeToCalendar, setColor, getEventSeriesById, setHidden, getTitle, newRecurrence, getAllOwnedCalendars, getOwnedCalendarById, getId, setTimeZone, getColor, getDescription, getDefaultCalendar, getEventsForDay, openByName, createCalendar, getAllCalendars, openByEmailAddress, getCalendarById, getOwnedCalendarsByName, createAllDayEventSeries, isHidden, createEvent, getEvents, isSelected, setDescription, getName, toString, setName, createEventFromDescription, getCalendarsByName, isOwnedByMe, setSelected]`

Has "toString" but that is commented out (I think). No "Color" in there either...

Thanks again!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What is the output of your logging and how does it differ from what you'd expect?

Comment: Thanks - sorry, it just returns blank where the substitutions. I also tried: `var colors = CalendarApp.Color;
  var cols;
  for (var x in colors) {
    cols += colors[x];
  }
  Logger.log(cols);` which gave me: "[14-08-29 10:04:43:582 EDT] undefinedfunction toString() {/*
*/}" without the quotes. Has the object's toString() method been commented out? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give the exact output from your original `Logger.log('Color Key: %s, Value: %s', x, colors[x])` loop?

Comment: Edited original with output from first version per cpburnz.

Comment: Added third try. Still a mystery...

Comment: That is very peculiar. I tried `Object.keys(Color)` but all I get is `toString` as well. Also, I tried `Object.getPrototypeOf(Color)` which is `null`, and `Object.getOwnProperty*(Color)` raise an ambiguous error. Unfortunately I'm at a loss. It appears as though non-function properties are completely absent from introspection in Google Script. It may be worth opening a new issue at: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: my bet is that all ENUM's should be made available through their internal ".values()" method, but maybe they haven't enabled this on all ENUM's. I have succeeded in using it for the FontFamily ENUM in DocumentApp (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587967/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-enums-in-google-apps-script). So I would say yes raise a new issue asking to make the ".values()" method available on all ENUMs.

Comment: Looks like this may be related to the following issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1389 - Do you agree?

Comment: Is this still an issue? I can't seem to find any fix.

Comment: For what it's worth, in other namespaces you have to call `.values()` to get an array of the enum values like 
`const elementTypeValues = DocumentApp.ElementType.values(); for (var elementTypeVal in elementTypeValues) { Logger.log(elementTypeVal); }`
but this doesn't work for `CalendarApp.Color`

Comment: It is no longer possible to iterate over the FontFamily ENUM in Google Apps Script, because the ENUM has been deprecated. In fact there is no way of knowing which Fonts are available to the user in any given document. I have [opened an issue on buganizer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154293771) to request this functionality, if you are interested please star the issue so it will be taken into consideration.