# Is it possible to iterate over ENUM's in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to get all available Font-families in a Google Apps Script for Google Docs. FontFamilies are defined as FontFamily ENUM. Can I iterate over this ENUM to get all the possible FontFamilies in this document?

UPDATE: I have found my own answer:

```js
var fontfamilies = DocumentApp.FontFamily.values();
for(var i in fontfamilies){
  Logger.log(fontfamilies[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So to answer my own question (I guess to have it show as an answer I can't just edit my original question), Google Apps ENUM's do have a "values()" property / method just like in Java. It will give an array with the ENUM values, in this case the names of the font families defined in the FontFamily ENUM.

Here is an example code to iterate over these values:

```js
var fontfamilies = DocumentApp.FontFamily.values();
for(var i in fontfamilies){
  Logger.log(fontfamilies[i]);
}
```

---

UPDATE april 2020:
It seems that the FontFamily ENUM [has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/font-family?hl=en), and currently there is no way to retrieve an array of font family names for font families that are currently available to the document. I have [opened an issue on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154293771), please star if you would appreciate this functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for all the enums... see this other post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561150/list-the-enum-keys-in-calendarapp-color.  If ever you find how to make it work please let us know. :-)

Comment: I guess it answers my specific case, but not the case of all ENUMs in google apps script... might be worth raising an issue in the code trac for google apps script (I've already raised a few myself!).

Comment: Unfortunately I am noticing that not all of the Fonts available in the document are being included in the ENUM... For example, I have added the `Bodoni` font to my document, but it is not included in the ENUM. Neither is `Cherry Cream Soda`. Others however are included in the ENUM such as `Dancing Script` and `Gloria Hallelujah`. Go figure.

Comment: It seems that the FontFamily ENUM [has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/font-family?hl=en). It seems that there is currently no way to retrieve an array of font family names for font families that are currently available to the document. I have [opened an issue on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154293771), please star if you would appreciate this functionality.